# Unable to retrieve createdDateTime along with mail,displayName of Azure AD Users

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to retrieve **createdDateTime** of Azure AD Users along with their Name and email address.

I found below commands:

- To connect to Azure AD:  `Connect-AzureAD`
- To retrieve the list of AzureAD users:
  `Get-AzureADUser`
- To retrieve specific attributes, I tried using below command:

```
Get-AzureADUser | Select-Object DisplayName, Mail, createdDateTime
```

It is returning name and email of users successfully.
But **createdDateTime** field is always empty for all users. I don't know where the problem is.

After retrieving all these, I want to export data to a CSV file that contains info like user's displayName, mail and their **createdDateTime.**

Can anyone help me out with the script or any suggestions?

Comment: that indicates that there is NO such property in the original objects. [*grin*] leave off the pipe & see what properties are actually there ... and then chose the correct one for export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that **`createdDateTime`** is an ***extension attribute***. That's why it won't be displayed normally.

In order to display **`createdDateTime`** of Azure AD Users along with their ***name*** and ***email address***, make use of below script:

```
$Info = @()
$AAD_users = Get-AzureADUser -All:$true
foreach ($AAD_User in $AAD_users) {
$objInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
Name     = $AAD_User.DisplayName
Email     = $AAD_User.mail
CreationDateTime  = (Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $AAD_User.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime")
}
$Info += $objInfo
}
$Info
```

[image]

***To export all this information to an CSV file, make use of below cmdlet:***

```
$Info | Export-csv -Path c:\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
```

[image]

To know more in detail, please find below **reference**:

[powershell - Gathering a list of both Standard Attr. and Extended attr. for Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71738239/gathering-a-list-of-both-standard-attr-and-extended-attr-for-azure/71791531#71791531)